# What is the little metal piece attached to the aperture ring in some Zeiss lenses?

Tags: lens, zeiss

What is the little metal piece attached to the aperture ring in some Zeiss lenses?

What is its purpose?

It is like a little gun sight.

See for example the Planar T* 1.4 50 where the "gun sight" is below the 5,6 number. [image: Planar T* 1.4 50]

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was a physical coupling for early built-in exposure meters. It hooked into a coupling pin on the camera body to tell the exposure meter what f-number the lens was set at.

It looked something like this:
[image: Nikon F2 Photomic]

*Nikon F2 Photomic, 1971, from [mir.com](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/htmls/models/htmls/slr7173.htm)*

Here's the [user's guide](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/hardwares/classics/nikonf2/prisms/dp1/index.htm), look for "Lens Aperture Coupling".

As for why Zeiss still has it on their lenses? I guess they don't want to leave owners of older cameras in the lurch :)

Comment: For sure, the external aperture coupling ring from the Nikon F. (I think it actually predated the F). I have six or eight Nikkor leses from this era. Sadly, many newer Nikon bodies will *not* mount these lenses. The F-mount is the same, but the tang has interference with the pentaprism on newer bodies.